# Underscore.js: Replace item in collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, underscore.js

I've been using underscore.js for a week now and I really like it.
However, now I want to replace a single element in collection (vm.lists) with another element.
I tried doing the following:

```
_.each(vm.lists, function (el) {
    if (el.id == list.id)
        el = list;
});
```

and:

```
var l = _.findWhere(vm.lists, { id: list.id });
l = list;
```

But none of them changes the actual item in the collection. How would I do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got pretty close. The issue is that you are only replacing the local variables (`el` and `l`) pointing to the value, and this does not modify the initial list. A simpler example:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3];
var v = list[1];
v = 7; // v will now point to a new value, but list will stay intact [1, 2, 3]
```

Same with objects:

```
var olist = [{id: 1, v: 2}, {id: 4, v: 6}];
var obj = olist[0];
obj = {id: 8, v: 10}; // changes what obj points to, but does not affect olist[0]

var obj2 = olist[0];
obj2.v = 777; // olist[0] still points to the same object but the object is modified

olist[0] = {id: 8, v: 10}; // changes what olist[0] points to
```

So basically you have two options:

a) change `vm.lists[index]` so that it points to a new object. You would need to get the index of the object in the list and do `vm.lists[index] = newObject;`. Note that some underscore predicates also provide you the index `_.each(list, function (el, index) {});`.

b) change the object that `vm.lists[index]` points to, but you would need to copy fields manually. For example, if your object is represented as `{id: id, values: [1, 2, 3], anotherField: data}`, you could copy the fields:

```
//el.id = list.id; // don't need this as you were searching by id
el.values = list.values;
el.anotherField = list.anotherField;
```

IMO the first option would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for underscore here:

```
for (var i = 0, l = vm.lists.length; i < l; i++)
{
  var el = vm.lists[i];
  if (el.id == list.id) {
    vm.lists[i] = list;
    break; // stop the for loop
  }
}
```